# After the update to iOS 14.1, my app only starts after a long waiting time (launch screen is then shown - then pause before the app runs)

Tags: ios, swift5

I made an app in which I access the calendar, everything works great - until I ubdated the iOS from 13.6 to 14.1 on the iPhone. I still have iOS 13.6 on the iPad and there it works as planned.
On the iPhone with 14.1 the app starts with the launch screen, but stays there a long time - there is no error message and no output in the debugger - after what feels like an eternity, the app starts and runs as usual.
What did I miss during the update?
Anyone know anything about what explains this pause?
Yes, I deleted and reinstalled the app on the iPhone.
I guess it's because of the authorization query that I changed as described at Apple. Still nothing.
Nothing happens in xCode - no message and no debug output. Nothing in the display of: CPU, memory, energy impact, disk or network.

I'll write my old authorization query here again - because I suspect the error there - so what should the correct authorization query be called? Can someone change my code correctly for iOS 14.1? I have not yet found any examples on the Internet - only available before iOS 14 (uTube etc.)
I am grateful for anyone who can make it clear to me what happens to changes in permissions. Sorry if I missed something fundamental. Many Thanks!

### (I orientated myself to "https://medium.com/better-programming/handling-location-permissions-in-ios-14-2cdd411d3cca".)

```
func checkCalendarAuthorizationStatusAndLoadCalendars() {

    logger(s: #function, f: #file)

    if locationManager == nil {
        setUpLocationManager()
    }
    /// here I need Help!
    let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event) /// <---- old!

    switch (status) {
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        /// This happens on first-run
        requestAccessToCalendar()

    case EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        /// Things are in line with being able to show the calendars in the table view
        /// Start and end date of the interval of 'weekOfYear's
        let temp = 60 * 60 * 24 * Int(365 / 2)
        let loadDuration = TimeInterval(temp)

        /// Creates a date value initialized relative to the current date and time by a given number of seconds.

        ....

        loadCalendars(loadCalendarFrom: &loadCalendarFrom, loadCalendarTo: &loadCalendarTo, eventStore: eventStore)

        refreshTableView()
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted, EKAuthorizationStatus.denied:
        /// We need to help them give us permission
        needPermissionView.fadeIn()
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

---

the call is here:

```
override
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    logger(s: #function, f: #file)

    //-----------------------

    formatter!.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter!.timeStyle = .short

    let dateString = formatter!.string(from: Date())       // "2020-06-03T01:43:44.888Z"
    let date:Date? = formatter!.date(from: dateString)!

    var localTimeZoneAbbreviation = String(TimeZone.current.abbreviation()!)

    let refereceTimeZoneAbbreviation = "CET"
    let cetTimeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: refereceTimeZoneAbbreviation)!

    if localTimeZoneAbbreviation == "MESZ" {
        localTimeZoneAbbreviation = "UTC+2"
    }
    if localTimeZoneAbbreviation == "MEZ" {
        localTimeZoneAbbreviation = "UTC+1"
    }
    checkCalendarAuthorizationStatusAndLoadCalendars()
}
```

Comment: Where do you call this from?I would suggest the following experiment: move this code to the viewDidAppear of the first view controller displayed and check if it makes a different. Sometimes the appearance of the first view controller is delayed if time consuming code is executed on earlier stages.

Comment: The code you are showing is pointless, since we don't know where you call it from and you don't show us the many other methods that it calls. Anyway, did you use Instruments? It will tell you _exactly_ what is taking up the time. There is no need to guess!

Comment: Thank you both, I've added the calling func.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this steps and the device has no more the slow deploy.
Maybe could help you.

1. Unpair your phone from xcode. The Xcode will crash but continue with the steps.

Launch xcode with your phone not plugged in

- plug your phone in

Under devices in xcode, unpair your phone.

2. stop xcode
3. run these on terminal

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ Device\ Logs
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

4. start xcode
5. plug phone in